# Constraint Violated Sqlite3 Android

Tags: android, sqlite, constraints, android-sqlite

```
  String CREATE_TRAIN_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + DATABASE_TRAIN_FEATURES
        + "("
        + KEY_ROW_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + KEY_USER_ID
        + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_COL_MEANX
        + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_COL_MEANY
        + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_COL_MEANZ
        + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_COL_VARIANCEX
        + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_COL_VARIANCEY
        + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_COL_VARIANCEZ
        + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_COL_CORRX
        + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_COL_CORRY
        + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_COL_CORRZ
        + " REAL NOT NULL,"
        + DATABASE_COL_Activity + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

In other place I add data:

```
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  String [] cols = setupCols(table);
  values.put(cols[0], email);
    int i = 1;
    for (Float reading : features) {
        values.put(cols[i], reading);
        ++i;
    }

  private String[] setupCols(String table) {
    if (DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_RAW_DATA.compareTo(table) != 0) {
        String[] columns = { DatabaseHelper.KEY_USER_ID,
                DatabaseHelper.KEY_COL_MEANX, DatabaseHelper.KEY_COL_MEANY,
                DatabaseHelper.KEY_COL_MEANZ,
                DatabaseHelper.KEY_COL_VARIANCEX,
                DatabaseHelper.KEY_COL_VARIANCEY,
                DatabaseHelper.KEY_COL_VARIANCEZ,
                DatabaseHelper.KEY_COL_CORRX, DatabaseHelper.KEY_COL_CORRY,
                DatabaseHelper.KEY_COL_CORRZ,
                DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_COL_Activity };
        return columns;
    } 
}
```

Everything looks okay ... in terms of the data. I don't see any nulls and the data itself looks reasonable for my application. But I keep getting constraint violated errors. I can't figure out why. Could it be the autoincrement part? That is, if I write some data, and then later try to rewrite some data (say, after I have restarted the app) will it try and re-add data with the primary key that has already been used. E.g., if I add some data with primary key of 1, then restart the app, and try to re-add data will it start again at 1?

Error Message:

```
  Error inserting Activity=Sitting VARIANCEY=0.0 CORRZ=0.0 VARIANCEZ=0.0 CORRY=0.0   
  user_id=admin CORRX=0.0 VARIANCEX=.233333332 MEANX = 617.7 MEANY=523.0 MEANZ=527.0
  android.database.sqlite.SQLLiteConstraintException:error code 19:constraint failed
```

Answer (score 0):

In your error message I do not see CORRX column which is defined as not null column.

Comment: It's there. Just added it. It should have been in there. But good catch anyways.